# How to create an IAsyncResult that immediately completes?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates, iasyncresult

I am implementing an interface which requires implementations of `BeginDoSomething` and `EndDoSomething` methods. However my `DoSomething` isn't really long-running. 
For simplicity assume `DoSomething` only compares two variables and return whether a > b

So my BeginDoSomething should be like:

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(int a, int b, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
     bool returnValue = a > b;
     return ...; //what should I return here?  
     //The method actually already completed and I don't need to wait for anything
 }
```

I don't know what I should return. I only implement `BeginDoSomething` because I have to, not because my method is long-running. Do I need to implement my own `IAsyncResult`? Is there an implementation already in .NET libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick hack way of doing it is to use a delegate:

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(int a, int b, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
     bool returnValue = a > b;
     Func<int,int,bool> func = (x,y) => x > y;
     return func.BeginInvoke(a,b,callback,state);
}
```

The downside of this approach, is that you need to be careful if two threads will be calling this method concurrently you'll get an error.

Comment: Not actually quick but hard to argue with the simplicity.  Omit returnValue.  I don't see the error.

Comment: what should be in the `EndDoSomething` then? I'm sorry I am very new on asynchronous programming

Comment: in End* it would be the same as func.BeginInvoke : IAsyncResult, so you are in effect delegating the responsibility to Delegate's implementation.

Comment: func.EndInvoke? but func is only declared in Begin* method, it can't be called in End*

Answer (score 6):

This is a little quick and dirty, but you can implement a class that implements IAsyncResult like so:

```
    public class MyAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        bool _result;

        public MyAsyncResult(bool result)
        {
            _result = result;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return _result; }
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

Then use it in your BeginDoSomething like this:

```
    return new MyAsyncResult(a > b);
```

Comment: I think the `AsyncWaitHandle` property should return a reference to a *set* `ManualResetEvent` (or similar). It's perfectly reasonable for clients to try to wait on the handle, and that shouldn't cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: True, we could do that, but as a WaitHandle is an expensive object, it seems wasteful to create one when it will **never** be relevant.

Comment: The code is missing the callback call, required (if not null).

Comment: Aww, ⁺¹, one have to implement only getters… It wan't obvious, I couldn't understand why `public bool IsCompleted` keeps be mentioned as not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am missing something but today you can just return `Task.CompletedTask`/`Task.FromResult`. `Task` implements `IAsyncResult`

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(int a, int b, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
     return Task.FromResult(a > b);
}
```

The `IAsyncResult.IsCompleted` is rightly `true` here. The `Func.BeginInvoke` approach wouldn't result in true.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you follow the directions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-tap-to-apm) to be able to create your implementations using Task based methods in case one of them does turn out to be long running.  If DoSomething is short running, you can block on it by creating a `Task` from its result

```
public IAsyncResult BeginDoSomething(int a, int b,
                                        AsyncCallback callback,
                                        object state)
{
   return Task.FromResult(DoSomething(a, b)).AsApm(callback, state);
}

public bool EndDoSomething(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   return ((Task<bool>)asyncResult).Result;
}

bool DoSomething(int a, int b)
{
   return a > b;
}

public static IAsyncResult AsApm<T>(this Task<T> task,
                                    AsyncCallback callback,
                                    object state)
{
    if (task == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("task");

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(state);
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
                      {
                         if (t.IsFaulted)
                            tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                         else if (t.IsCanceled)
                            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                         else
                            tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);

                         if (callback != null)
                            callback(tcs.Task);
                      }, TaskScheduler.Default);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```